# Adding Spree to your Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am following the spree Documentation at [guides.spreecommerce.org](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html)

But I am getting an error:

> Could not find gem 'spree (~> 3.1.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
>   Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Comment: share your gem file

Comment: https://ideone.com/dgQmCk

Comment: If my answer was helpful you can mark at as correct

Answer (score 0):

Actually your gem file has specified rails 5 so you need to try this

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'
```